# SQL to find course popularity from a survey

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, case, sql-order-by

I am trying to write an SQL query that displays the course popularity,
in descending order.

- Course popularity is measured in points, which determined as follows: **For every survey:**
- a. if the votes difference > 10% of total votes, the more popular course gets 1 point, and  the less popular course gets 0 points
- b. if the votes difference <= 10% of total votes, each course gets 0.5
  point

| course_id | course_name | faculty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | economics_101 | business |
| 1002 | algebra_101 | math |
| 1003 | geometry_101 | math |
| 1004 | management_101 | business |
| 1005 | marketing_101 | business |
| 1006 | physics_101 | science |

| survey_id | option_a | option_b | votes_a | votes_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | economics_101 | geometry_101 | 61 | 34 |
| 2002 | algebra_101 | economics_101 | 31 | 68 |
| 2003 | marketing_101 | management_101 | 11 | 72 |
| 2005 | management_101 | algebra_101 | 43 | 54 |
| 2004 | geometry_101 | marketing_101 | 48 | 46 |

Result achieved so far:

| course | popularity |
| --- | --- |
| economics_101 | 4 |
| management_101 | 2 |
| algebra_101 | 2 |
| marketing_101 | 1 |
| geometry_101 | 1 |
| [NULL] | 0 |

I managed to join it so far, would be great to have inputs on optimizing this query:

```
    WITH x AS 
(
WITH b AS 

(

WITH a as 
(
select * from course c
LEFT  JOIN survey s
on c.course_name = s.option_a 

UNION ALL 

select * from course c
LEFT  JOIN survey s
on c.course_name = s.option_b
)

SELECT a.*,
SUM(votes_a+votes_b) as total_votes,
CASE WHEN (a.votes_a - a.votes_b) > (0.1*SUM(votes_a+votes_b))  THEN 1 
     WHEN (a.votes_b - a.votes_a) <= (0.1*SUM(votes_a+votes_b))  THEN 0.5
     ELSE 0
END AS 'Popularity_a',

CASE WHEN (a.votes_b - a.votes_a) > (0.1*SUM(votes_a+votes_b))  THEN 1 
     WHEN (a.votes_a - a.votes_b) <= (0.1*SUM(votes_a+votes_b))  THEN 0.5
     ELSE 0
END AS 'Popularity_b'


FROM 
a
GROUP BY 
a.course_name ,
a.course_id,
a.faculty ,
a.survey_id ,
a.option_a ,
a.option_b ,
a.votes_a ,
a.votes_b 
)

SELECT b.option_a  as course,
b.Popularity_a as pop
FROM b
LEFT JOIN 
course cx 
ON b.option_a  = cx.course_name  

UNION ALL 

SELECT b.option_b as course ,
b.Popularity_b as pop
FROM b
LEFT JOIN 
course cx 
ON b.option_b  = cx.course_name 
)

select
x.course ,
sum (x.pop) as popularity
from x
GROUP BY
x.course 

order by popularity desc
```

Comment: i cant really fully understand your question.. may what i understand is you want to do some calculation and get the popularity as one column value.... in that case you can use if else.. like 'SELECT CASE WHEN (s.votes_a - s.votes_b) > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Popularity'; ..

Comment: Thanks @saravanan049, Yes absolutely, I am trying to calculate the popularity of the courses based on the difference in votes - and it is based on 2 criteria as above

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: The expected results for the given data would be useful.

Comment: subtract row by row (option_a -option_b) or based on course(economics_101-economics_101).?

Comment: I am using SQLite and I have tried using cte and getting the result that I should. It would be great if anyone can provide with some optimization inputs,.

Comment: Your results seems to be incorrect. `economics` should get 1 point for survey 2001 and 1 point for survey 2002, so 2 points in total. Or am I missing something?

Comment: For optimization I would not use nested `WITH` statement, because they will use debugging/changing your SQL more difficult (or needless complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to extract all courses and the respective points they get from the table `survey` and aggregate to get the `popularity`.
Then join to `course`:

```
WITH 
  cte AS (
    SELECT option_a course_name, 
           CASE 
             WHEN votes_a - votes_b > 0.1 * (votes_a + votes_b) THEN 1.0 
             WHEN votes_b - votes_a > 0.1 * (votes_a + votes_b) THEN 0.0
             ELSE 0.5 
           END points
    FROM survey
    UNION ALL
    SELECT option_b, 
           CASE 
             WHEN votes_b - votes_a > 0.1 * (votes_a + votes_b) THEN 1.0 
             WHEN votes_a - votes_b > 0.1 * (votes_a + votes_b) THEN 0.0
             ELSE 0.5 
           END
    FROM survey
  ),
  points AS (
    SELECT course_name, SUM(points) total_points
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY course_name
  )
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(p.total_points, 0) popularity
FROM course c LEFT JOIN points p
ON p.course_name = c.course_name
ORDER BY popularity DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=81055b5f3e9d97c321ab3d6de33bd8c2).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it works! 
Mine was giving similar results in terms of ranking BUT the points I seem to have doubled.